# Plugin JARs are missing in an application built with Tycho

Tags: plugins, maven, jar, tycho

I am building an Eclipse application with Maven Tycho. I managed to create the pom files for building the plugins and features. I ran install on them and got Build successful. I have also cretaed the pom for the application (product) and set the Packaging to "eclipse-application". The application is feature-based. I ran install and got the Build successful. I got the generated folder for the application, containing the folders "plugins" and "features".

The problem is that not all the jar files, for all the plugins, can be found in the plugins folder. I can find the jar files for the plugins that are listed in the features. But the jar files for the plugins listed in the Dependencies tab of other plugins are not generated. In other words, only the plugins referenced in the features are generated as jar files, while the jar files for the ones referenced in the plugins are not generated.

Obviously, I cannot run the application without them. What am I doing wrong? How can I get all the required jar files generated?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use `eclipse-application`. It has been deprecated, and, being someone that has tried to make it work with his own projects, I can tell you that it's a **bad** idea as it has a lot of problems. Instead, use `eclipse-repository`.

Secondly, the only .jar files that will show up in your products `plugins` directory will be ones that have compiled successfully, and are also in the dependencies section of your .product file, and **not** your manifest.mf.

I suspect that your problem is related to the second point, but I've seen `eclipse-application` do so many odd things that it alone might resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is on the right track... Use *eclipse-repository*.

To have Tycho generate a repository, you are probably using the *tycho-p2-repository-plugin* ... And if you're using that plugin, then you may want to add this little element to the configuration section.

```
<includeAllDependencies>true</includeAllDependencies>
```

Here's a larger sample of my pom.xml that's in my p2repository plugin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>my.domain.product</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../my.domain.product.parent</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>my.domain.product.p2repository</artifactId>
<packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>
<name>My Product - P2 Repository</name>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>${tycho-groupid}</groupId>
      <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${tycho-version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <includeAllDependencies>true</includeAllDependencies>
        <createArtifactRepository>true</createArtifactRepository>
        <compress>true</compress>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

Hope this helps.